# Тригер на изменение таблицы

Tags: sql, update, триггер

```
   USE [test]
   GO
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[nameTriger]    Script Date:      07.03.2016 21:09:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[nameTriger] ON [test].[dbo].[name]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @OldName nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @oldID INT 
SET @OldName = (SELECT [name]
FROM [test].[dbo].[name] WHERE id = @@IDENTITY);
SET @oldID = (SELECT  [id]
FROM [test].[dbo].[name] WHERE id = @@IDENTITY );

BEGIN
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[nameHistory] (id, name)
VALUES (@oldID, @OldName)
  END
END
```

Он хорошо отрабатывает, если одна строка обновляется, если несколько, то в таблицу аудита пишет только одну строку.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так? Или нельзя уловить обновление больше одной строки за одну команду update?

Comment: СУБД-то какая? Уточните в мануале, как указать FOR EACH ROW или FOR EACH STATEMENT (вызов триггера на каждую строку в отдельности или только на целый запрос). Судя по поведению, у вас сейчас FOR EACH STATEMENT.

Comment: @Мелкий судя по квадратным скобкам в коде - это MS SQL. И судя по гуглу там нет разделения на row/statement.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190752(v=sql.120).aspx     ,       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625014/multiple-row-update-sql-trigger-from-single-update-sql-statement

Comment: @Mike, я правильно понял, что нужно делать запрос не из основных таблиц, а из виртуальных?

Comment: @one__for__one Да, судя по всему  там есть как минимум таблица `inserted` старые данные видимо надо доставать из основной таблицы по id из inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[nameTriger] ON [test].[dbo].[name]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[nameHistory] (id, name)
select id, name from deleted
END
```